# Escaped Double Quotes with MessageFormat

Tags: java, json, messageformat

I have the following String in JSON format:

```
String message = "{ \"message\": \"Hello World!\" }";
```

But I want to set it up to use MessageFormat:

```
String message = MessageFormat.format("{ \"message\": \"Hello {0}!\" }", "World");
```

I know MessageFormat uses single quotes vs backslash to escape characters, but I am not seeing a way around using a backslash here since I need the double quotes in the message and without the backslash, the unescaped double quotes break the string.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape outer braces so put `{` and `}` in single quotes :

```
 String message = MessageFormat.format("'{' \"message\": \"Hello {0}!\" '}'", "World");
```

Comment: This was it. I don't know how I missed those outer braces.

Answer (score 0):

Use two escape characters for the escape character, and an escaped quote for the quote.

```
String message = MessageFormat.format("{ \\\"message\\\": \\\"Hello {0}!\\\" }", "World");
```